# Vee-validate returning form is always valid when using <Field>

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate

everyone.
I'm working in a Vue 3 project and using vee-validate v4.
I have my forms like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <VForm
      v-slot="{ meta }"
      ref="form"
    >
      <VField
        v-slot="{ field, errors: nameErrors }"
        name="name"
        rules="required|min:6"
      >
        <va-input
          v-bind="field"
          v-model="account.data.name"
          class="mb-4"
          :label="$t('register.name')"
          :error="nameErrors && nameErrors.length > 0"
          :error-messages="nameErrors"
        />
      </VField>
    </VForm>
  </div>
</template>
```

I using the new **script setup** and my code is like this

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { useForm } from "vee-validate";
  const form = useForm();
  const save = async function() {
    const validate = await form.validate() as any;
    if (validate.valid) {
      // My save logic
    }
  }
</script>
```

But the *validate.valid* is always true, even the form has validation errors. There is a way to correct this?
I do a test with validation schema, and this works, but need some more code to show the errors on fields, or I need to duplicate the rules from  into the schema.
There is a way to use *form.validate()* with the rules in the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT use `useForm` Composition API and `<Form>` component at the same time. Either use one or another. This way you are creating two different form contexts at the same time

Your `form` created by `useForm()` is always valid because it has no fields.

What you want is to use form context created by `<VForm>` component. Just replace `const form = useForm();` with `const form = ref()`

Or use a [well described way of form submit in the docs](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/components/handling-forms#using-handlesubmit) - no need for template refs or calling `validate()` manually as Vee-Validate will call your submit handler only if form is valid...